# Is there an R function that colors blocks for a given vector of values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a vector of 100 values, and I'd like to plot an intensity graph according to the values in a graph equally divided with 10 little squares.

I'm trying to use ggplot2 package in R, but I'm stuck. Below is my code

```
> vec <- rnorm(100,5,4) #100-vector

> ggplot(NULL)  + geom_vline(xintercept = 1:10) + geom_hline(yintercept = 1:10)+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(.45, 9.55), ylim = c(.45,9.553))+
  theme(legend.box.spacing = unit(0, "mm"),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black",fill=NA),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())  #the graph with 100 blocks
[enter image description here][1]
```

I expect plot the colors in this graph according to the values to the "vec" variable, e.g. shades from red to smaller numbers, going dark blue to larger numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more-or-less what you want. With `ggplot`, you need to plot data frames, not just random vectors. And we need to create columns to map to the x and y axes:

```
set.seed(47)
vec <- rnorm(100,5,4)
dd = expand.grid(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
dd$vec = vec

ggplot(dd, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = vec)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "firebrick4", high = "dodgerblue2")
```

[image]

You might have better luck with other palettes, e.g., `scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")` is pretty nice.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote your answer, but anyway, thank you very much!